# Has this Principal Component Analysis (PCA) been done correctly?

Tags: signal-analysis, python

I have a set of **3D data points**, indicated by the **blue** color in the picture below.

I then **project them onto the x-y plane**, i.e. setting z values of all the points to 0, shown by the **yellow** color below.

Then, I perform PCA on the 2D data points (the yellow ones).

I end up with the **1st Principal Component** being the **green** line, and the 2nd being the yellow line.

[image]

As I am a newbie in PCA, I am not sure whether I have done something wrong or not.

Because in my intuitive, the 1st Principal Component should be like in the picture below:

[image]

*I mean unlike the above picture given in wiki, my 1st component is NOT obvious and seems to make no sense.* **Did I do something wrong?**

**Edit:**

To avoid the confusion, the 2D view from the above is as follows: 
[image]

Comment: Two suggestions: could you explain why you project the data onto the xy plane (PCA can be done in 3-dimensional data too!)? If the third dimension is not really important to your problem, it would be better to post 2D plots - the 3D graph is hard to read.

Comment: @pichenettes  yeah the 3rd dimension is not important to my purpose. Do u need me to post the 2D view (view from the top of x-y plane)? Thanks!

Comment: @pichenettes  please see attached

Comment: A pure 2D view would have been better...

Comment: @pichenettes  any idea? :)

Comment: Have you centered your data?

Comment: @pichenettes  by center u mean to subtract the mean?

Comment: yes. and tell us more about why your result doesn't meet your expectations.

Answer (score 1):

If the PCA was correct, than green and yellow line would be perpendicular. So something is wrong with your result.

Comment: I am almost sure that the green and yellow lines are perpendicular. The x and y axes do not have the same scale; and because this is a silly 3D projection, the gray grid in the background is not reliable (parallax error).

Comment: You are right, i missed the different scaling of the axes.